# Jquery click() function doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a script which removes items from an input with CSV. It works except in Explorer

http://jsfiddle.net/BXWqK/21/

What could be the cause? I can't figure it out... !

Comment: Does any error occur? Try adding breakpoints or `alert()` statements inside of your code to see exactly where IE dies...

Comment: Works fine on IE9. Can you say what version you are testing, exactly?

Comment: it is an issue with indexOf and IE. Older versions of IE don't support indexOf for arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you're talking about older versions of Internet Explorer (the newer version being 9, and your script works on it).

Then it's probably because of `Array.indexOf`, Internet Explorer used to not have that function. See [Array.indexOf in Internet Explorer](http://soledadpenades.com/2007/05/17/arrayindexof-in-internet-explorer/).

By the way, `jQuery.inArray` also returns the value's index within the array. So doing this is pretty redundant:

```
if ($.inArray(fruit_remove, fruits_array) > -1) {
   var fruit_index = fruits_array.indexOf(fruit_remove);
   ...
```

Comment: You're very likely to be right about the cause.
As for solution I would suggest using [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#indexOf), which implements indexOf to work on all browsers (in the format `_(haystack).indexOf(needle)`), delegating to internal implementation where possible

Comment: @Bertrand Marron, thank you! Based on that I can fix it! :) Are you suggesting to remove the if statement? Without it, if the id of a `remove` div differs from the name in the array, it will remove the last value in the text input. With the statement nothing happens ,should there be a wrong id name.

Comment: What @Bertrand is suggesting is something like this: `var fruit_index = $.inArray(fruit_remove, fruits_array); if(fruid_index > -1) { ...`

Comment: @Xint0, perhaps I don't understand because I lack experience.. I tried the method and now the if statement makes the script not work http://jsfiddle.net/BXWqK/31/

Comment: @CyberJunkie, obviously `fruid_index` (with a *d*) in `if(fruid_index > -1)` was a typo. Try using `fruit_index`. You can easily discover errors like those by yourself by opening up the JavaScript console of your browser, in this case it'll tell you something like `fruid_index is not defined`.

Comment: aah sorry lol. I tend to overlook minor issues with code I'm not familiar with. I am using Chrome which doesn't seem to have js console. Thanks again!

Comment: @CyberJunkie, Chrome does have a very good built-in JavaScript console. See [Chrome Developer Tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html).